# Node.js fetch returns empty data

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get some data from an API using `fetch`, and the console log shows `[]`, however, when I do the same request using Postman, it successfully returns a JSON. What am I doing wrong?

```
let fetch = require("node-fetch");

const url_deals = 'http://www.cheapshark.com/api/1.0/deals';

function getDealInfo(dealID){
    let new_url = new URL(url_deals + "?id=" + dealID);

    fetch(new_url, {method : 'GET'})
        .then(data =>{
            data.json().then(out => {
                console.log(out);
            })
        })
}

getDealInfo("X8sebHhbc1Ga0dTkgg59WgyM506af9oNZZJLU9uSrX8%253D");
```

[image: Postman screenshot]

Comment: I thing you are not using the same identifier, when I'm trying this url http://www.cheapshark.com/api/1.0/deals?id=X8sebHhbc1Ga0dTkgg59WgyM506af9oNZZJLU9uSrX8%253D the response its an empty array just like you.

Comment: I got empty result from the link so it seems nothing wrong. are you sure about id? X8sebHhbc1Ga0dTkgg59WgyM506af9oNZZJLU9uSrX8 seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id is apparently encoded multiple times.  If I decode it twice, I get this:

```
getDealInfo("X8sebHhbc1Ga0dTkgg59WgyM506af9oNZZJLU9uSrX8=");
```

And, that actually fetches this data.

```
{ gameInfo:
   { storeID: '1',
     gameID: '93503',
     name: 'BioShock Infinite',
     steamAppID: '8870',
     salePrice: '29.99',
     retailPrice: '29.99',
     steamRatingText: 'Overwhelmingly Positive',
     steamRatingPercent: '95',
     steamRatingCount: '61901',
     metacriticScore: '94',
     metacriticLink: '/game/pc/bioshock-infinite',
     releaseDate: 1364169600,
     publisher: 'N/A',
     steamworks: '1',
     thumb:
      'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/8870/capsule_sm_120.jpg?t=1568739647' },
  cheaperStores:
   [ { dealID: 'fq0cNHiR3Z4TpZyV7WH865C1%2BCBlmufYUc%2Bu2HqyUHE%3D',
       storeID: '27',
       salePrice: '26.99',
       retailPrice: '29.99' } ],
  cheapestPrice: { price: '5.27', date: 1543553226 } }
```

So it, appears that the id value you're passing is incorrect.  You can see that the `node-fetch()` code is working fine by just using it with the base URL: `http://www.cheapshark.com/api/1.0/deals` and that will return you JSON, confirming that the `node-fetch()` code works just fine and the issue is with your `id` value.

Comment: Just found it decoding it online as well. It seems all deal IDs are encoded, so I need to decode them first. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @BrunoSignorelliDomingues - I googled URL decoder and went here: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/.  You can also do it programmatically if required using [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

Comment: Had to implement a loop that keeps on decoding the URL until it is no longer able to decode so I could detect those multiple encodings. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your ID. You've escaped it twice.

```
getDealInfo("X8sebHhbc1Ga0dTkgg59WgyM506af9oNZZJLU9uSrX8%253D");
```

Id in your code is `X8sebHhbc1Ga0dTkgg59WgyM506af9oNZZJLU9uSrX8%253D` but in the screenshot it is `X8sebHhbc1Ga0dTkgg59WgyM506af9oNZZJLU9uSrX8%3D`. Look at the 3rd to last digit.

Answer (score 0):

Using that ID I also get nothing.

Note that if you make the request with no `id` the IDs do not match your format, e.g.,

```
"dealID":"tnXImZO%2FYSnkve2w7O5fHy77qn0e8uvWFbkiT%2Fjb7r0%3D"
```

It looks like you have an extra URI encoding going on somewhere.